# React Native loop this API to Display

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native

[React-Native] How to loop JSON API for this play with conditional rendering
I'm a newbie please guide me thank you.

My code :  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3x6OW2-ZXs6SGgxWmtFTFRHV00/view

[This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOiTZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

API Key has limited now.
use this it's worked

https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers?api_key=q9Tuf53gQldj9vJVY1tILtOcfILTfHRJyR7GXVHZ